# Keycloak Docker import LDAP bind credentials without exposing them

Tags: docker, security, ldap, passwords, keycloak

I have a keycloak docker image and I import the configuration of my realm from a json file. And it works, so far so good.

But in my configuration there is an LDAP provider, which doesn't have the right credentials (Bind DN and Bind Credentials). They are not inserted in the JSON due to security purposes. So I have to manually insert the credentials in the Admin Console after startup.

I am now trying to find a secure way to automate that without exposing the credentials in clear text, so that we don't have to manually insert the credentials after each startup.

I thought about inserting them in the JSON file inside the container with a shell script or whatever and then importing the resulting file when starting keycloak. The problem is that the credentials would then be exposed in clear text in the JSON file inside the container. So anybody with access to the container would be able to see them.

I'm thinking about inserting the credentials in that JSON file based on environment variables (these are securely stored in the Gitlab runner and masked in the logs), starting keycloak and then removing the JSON file on the fly after keycloak successfully starts without exposing the credentials in any of the layers. But I couldn't find a way to do that.

Can anybody think of an idea of how this can be achieved?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to bind your keycloak instance to an external database with a persistent volume ([examples from keycloak here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/master/docker-compose-examples)) and to change the migration strategy from OVERWRITE_EXISTING, to IGNORE_EXISTING ([documentation here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_export_import)) in your docker-compose, like this:

`command: '-b 0.0.0.0 -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING'`

In this way, your configuration is persistent so you just enter your LDAP credentials the first time and don't need complex operations with pipelines.